# Есть ли ошибка в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Никто — ни муж, ни жена, — сильно не огорчился.

Answer (score 2):

Никто: ни муж, ни жена — сильно не огорчились (классический вариант:смысловое выделение однородного ряда, глагол в форме мн.числа). Никто — ни муж, ни жена — сильно не огорчился (замена двоеточия тире: смысловое выделение обобщающего слова, однородный ряд в добавочном сообщении, глагол в форме ед.числа).

Comment: Не обратила внимания на форму сказуемого. Не могу найти подобных примеров с рекомендациями. Судя по другим случаям форма сказуемого(единственное или множественное)вариативна. Я бы сказала в единственном, согласуя с обобщающим словом. София,дайте ссылку на источник, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, "ни муж, ни жена" - это приложение? Тогда естественно согласовать сказуемое в числе с подлежащим. И, конечно, запятая после второго тире не нужна: 
Никто - ни муж, ни жена - не огорчился.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы после "никто" поставила двоеточие

Comment: Судя по интенивности и типу вопросов, это примеры из домашнего задания.

Comment: И вторую запятую нужно убрать. Fuchoin Kazuki, как Вы отличаете, домашнее задание это или нет? Вроде вопрос элементарный...

Comment: Да, собственно, по тону отличаю))) Когда человек спрашивает то, что его интересует, он обычно как-то комментирует свой вопрос, ведь правда? А тут вопрос, как из учебника: "Исправьте", "укажите ошибки". В приказной форме.   
И, кстати, зачем убрали сам вопрос. Я буду вынуждена его вообще закрыть.

Answer (score 0):

Никто-ни муж, ни жена -сильно не огорчился.